# React Native google auth. Access blocked: Authentication error. Error 400: invalid request

Tags: reactjs, iphone, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42BTK.jpg)

I am trying to setting up google authentication in my React native app with Firebase and Google Cloud Oauth. But this is the issue I’m facing if I try to test the auth

I was expecting a consent screen with the users already saved credentials or a form for users to input their credentials

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your React Native app requests the necessary permissions for authentication. If using Expo, make sure you have the required permissions in your app.json file.